# How can I use different master_docs in HTML and LaTeX?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, toctree

Because of discrepancies in the ways indexes and `toctree` captions are processed by builders, I'd like to use a different 'master' document for the HTML and LaTeX builds of my Sphinx document.

The following almost works:

```
def set_master_doc(app):
    if app.tags.has("latex"):
        app.config.master_doc = "latex"
        app.config.exclude_patterns.append("html.rst")
    else:
        app.config.master_doc = "html"
        app.config.exclude_patterns.append("latex.rst")

def setup(app):
    app.connect('builder-inited', set_master_doc)
```

… but since it modifies the configuration, it causes a full rebuild every time I switch from HTML to LaTeX, and vice-versa.

I also tried to have an index with `only::`:

```
.. only:: html

   .. include:: html.rst

.. only:: latex

   .. include:: latex.rst
```

… but this causes many issues, including duplicate table-of-contents entries, because both documents are parsed and indexed.

What's the right way to use a different master doc for my LaTeX and HTML builds?

Comment: I think an example in Pyramid's docs may help. Here's possibly relevant code in [`conf.py`](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L194-L200) and compare [`index.rst`](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/docs/index.rst) to [`latexindex.rst`](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/docs/latexindex.rst).

Comment: Hm, yeah, that almost works.  The problem is that Sphinx still processes (parses and references) both documents (when building the html docs, it also creates a `latexindex.html`), and links to target defined in both places end up pointing to `latexindex.html`